# Geting Fatal Error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new to Zend Framework, try to configure on my local machine. 
Geting Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded' in C:\Inetpub\ZendFramework-1.10.6\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php on line 103

Could anybody please help me

Comment: Please show the code you are using.

Comment: Have you loaded/installed the PDO extension it asks for?

Comment: I just downloaded the ZendFramework-1.10.6 from zend quickstart and copy it on C:\Inetpub\ZendFramework-1.10.6. I have project which i need to work for some changes at C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Project\
and on project\public\index.php set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
    'c:/inetpub/wwwroot/projectB/library',
    '../../../ZendFramework-1.10.6/library',
)));

Comment: @Baju I have not installed PDO extension could you please tell me how should i install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to install the PDO extension:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setup.php

Comment: PDO is nothing do here. It is a error of DB connection. Zend use PDO by default.

Comment: Thanks I installed PDO now i am geting Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'teamkit'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in C:\Inetpub\ZendFramework-1.10.6\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php on line 144

Comment: So you're connecting with the wrong credentials or the user you specified isn't allowed to access the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change a settings of DB in configs/ or settings/. All parameters is right? servername, username, password, database name?